# Convert Unix time into readable Date in Java

Tags: java, datetime

What is the easiest way to do this in Java? Ideally I will be using Unix time in milliseconds as input and the function will output a String like

November 7th, 2011 at 5:00 PM

Comment: Have you looked at Calendar?: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Why don't you fool around with [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for a bit and let us know if/when you get stuck?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
String date = sdf.format(myTimestamp);
```

Comment: This works really well, except when the ends in a '0', such as 1:40 or 5:20, the 0 won't be displayed.

Comment: Sorry, try h:mm instead of h:m

Comment: I was getting jan 1970 as output when my timestamp was of jan 2015. Multiplying timestamp by 1000L does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to convert my unix_timestamps like 1372493313 to human readable format like Jun 29 4:08.

The above answered helped me for my Android app code. A little difference was that on Android it recommends to use locale settings as well, and my original unix_timestamp was in seconds, not milliseconds, and Eclipse wanted to add try/catch block or throw exception. So my working code has to be modified a bit like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param unix_timestamp
 * @return
 * @throws ParseException 
 */
private String unixToDate(String unix_timestamp) throws ParseException {    
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(unix_timestamp) * 1000;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d H:mm", Locale.CANADA);
    String date = sdf.format(timestamp);

    return date.toString();
}
```

And here is the calling code:

```
String formatted_timestamp;
try {
        formatted_timestamp = unixToDate(unix_timestamp); // timestamp in seconds
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date((long) time * 1000L);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```